# How to ignore wrap element when parse json to dto

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I have a json like this

```
{
 "135": {
  "id": "135",
  "name": "My Awesome Washing Machine!",
  "powerswitch": {
   "available": "true",
   "state": "on",
   "reachable": "true",
   "locked": "false"
  },
  "reference": {
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Lave-linge",
   "category_id":"2"
 }
},
 "491": {
  "id": "491",
  "name": "My Fridge",
  "powerswitch": {
   "available": "true",
   "state": "on",
   "reachable": "false",
   "locked": "false"
  },
  "reference": {
   "id": "1",
   "name": "Réfrigérateur",
   "category_id":"1"
  }
 }
}
```

And here is my dto:

```
public class Device {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private DevicePowerswitch powerswitch;
    private DeviceReference reference;
    //getter, setter
}
```

The question is how can I parse json to a list of device.
Note that there is a non-static id value wrapper in this above json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to parse the JSON into a JsonNode, and  then iterate over the children.  The nodes you pull out as a result can then be mapped using an ObjectMapper to Device instances.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(JSON);
for (JsonNode node : jsonNode)
{
    final Device device = mapper.convertValue(node,
                                              Device.class);
    // do something with the device
}
```

Comment: @Lep Please accept the answer if it's correct; this helps others find answers.